# Postfix: bouncing mail (reverse DNS issue)

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, reverse-dns, email-bounces

I have a problem with Postfix. I get this with some email address:

```
to=<mail@domain.tld>, relay=mail.domain.tld[IP_ADDRESS]:25, delay=3, delays=0/0/2.5/0.52, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mail.domain.tld[IP_ADDRESS] said: 550 5.7.1 <mail@domain.tld>... Fix reverse DNS for MY_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS,or use your ISP server (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

I read something and it should be related to my HELO/EHLO hostname. Postfix runs on the same server of the script sending mails, same IP address.
When I type hostname -f ubuntu returns "localhost". But in /etc/hostname I have "domain.tld" (one of my domains).

Here's my main.cf file:

```
### Postfix SMTP Server
myhostname = $mydomain
mydomain = domain.tld
myorigin = $mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (multiformeingegno)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
relayhost = 
inet_interfaces = all
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled

mydestination = domain.tld, localhost.domain.tld, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_protocols = all
```

Comment: You've specified the domain which helps a bit. 1. Do you have an MX record for `multiformeingegno.it` ? 2. What is the mailserver hostname  `mail.multiformeingegno.it`? Have you either set up, or requested RDNS for that hostname?

Comment: I have no MX record for multiformeingegno.it. But I can manage them.. Should I set my Server IP address as MX server?

Comment: Well, an MX record should be something like `IN  MX  10  mail.multiformeingegno.it` then you will need an A record for `mail`. The A record should be your server IP. In boca al lupo!

Comment: Can't it be the domain itself and not mail.domain.tld ?

Answer (score 3):

Assume your mail server name is `multiformeingegno.it` (`myhostname` value in postfix) and your server has two IPs `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5` and you are sending a mail from `user@otherdomain.tld`, setting up all the following is always recommended.

- `A` record of `multiformeingegno.it` pointing to `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5`
- PTR record for `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5` pointing to `multiformeingegno.it`
- `SPF` record for `otherdomain.tld` should include both `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5`
- `otherdomain.tld` should have proper `MX` record or a `A` record

Hope that was clear. To clarify you one more thing, your system's name has nothing to do here.

Comment: Well I have all of these except that PTR of my server's IP is by default my VPS name (which is just "multiformeingegno", not "multiformeingegno.it"). To change it I have to change my VPS name. I'm going to try now

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Ya ok. Check the "THE FQDN" paragraph in "man hostname"

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, you need to make sure that your PTR record for your server's IP address corresponds to your server's advertised hostname.

Your hosting provider (or whoever provided you with the IP address) should be able to help you with this, as reverse DNS administration (usually) lies with the controlling ISP, normally defined in WHOIS.

Essentially, whatever IP your server resolves to **must** have a reverse DNS pointing to the **same** hostname, or at a minimum Postfix's `myhostname` configuration variable, which is the name it uses when sending a `HELO` request to another SMTP server.

This is more than simply good practice when you run a public mailserver, as checking PTR addresses is part of the anti-spam setup of many mailserver administrators (including me) due to the fact that many spammers use dynamic IP addresses or non-matching A/PTR combinations.

A slightly more in-depth explanation is this:

- The bounce message you're seeing is being generated by the **receiving** MTA at `mail.domain.tld`.
- This server sees that your Postfix server is using the IP `1.2.3.4` (I've used a placeholder as you haven't given yours).
- The receiving MTA checks the RDNS entry for `1.2.3.4` against the hostname that it appears to be from according to the `HELO` it receives.
- If the RDNS matches, it shows you are a responsible mailserver admin and the mail passes that particular check
- **Be aware** that this is just one check, and your message may fail others.

A real-world example:

```
~ $ nslookup vps.vikingserv.net
Server:     192.168.50.11
Address:    192.168.50.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   vps.vikingserv.net
Address: 31.3.251.12

~ $ nslookup 31.3.251.12
Server:     192.168.50.11
Address:    192.168.50.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
12.251.3.31.in-addr.arpa    name = vps.vikingserv.net.
```

Comment: Uhm I had a look at my VPS control panel (DigitalOcean). My IP by default has a PTR with same name of the droplet with a dot at the end (multiformeingegno.) . What should I do? Maybe change the droplet name to "multiformeingegno.it" ? So it's the same domain of the hostname I specified in /etc/hostname ?